# negative voltage sources and KVL

Tags: voltage, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPpGaZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I choose clockwise current direction then KVL gives me:
$$10\text{V}+5\text{k}\Omega \times I-0.7=0 \rightarrow I=-1.86\text{mA}$$ 
If I choose counter clockwise current direction KVL gives me:
$$-10\text{V}+5\text{k}\Omega \times I+0.7=0 \rightarrow I=+1.86\text{mA}$$

I want to ask if I am doing something wrong or the negative current in the first case is because the assumed current direction is backwards to the actual flow?

Comment: Yes.  A negative just indicates assumed direction is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you're absolutely correct in both cases. A negative magnitude of a vector is the same as a positive magnitude on the vector in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is  perfectly correct , to have a better clarification check the image below

[image]